# How to test the Text area that appears below the textbox using Selenium

Tags: selenium

I am testing a registration flow using Selenium.

In that, a user has to validate his/her account by clicking on the link sent to his/her email. A registration form is displayed to the user after clicking on the link. The registration form contains various fields like `name`, `EmailId` etc. The first field in the form contains a `Company` text box. If the user's company is registered (if the user is not the first user from his company) then the `Company` field is auto filled with the respective company and is not editable and a text is displayed stating "There are n number of people already using this form".

How can I test the text using Selenium where every time I run the test case, the `n` value should increment?

Comment: Which part of Selenium are you using? Selenium IDE? Selenium RC (a.k.a. Selenium 1)? Selenium WebDriver (a.k.a. Selenium 2)? In which programming language?

Comment: I am using Selenium IDE with java as the programming language

Comment: So you're recording a testcase in IDE and then exporting it to Java's WebDriver, right?

Comment: I am not using a web driver. Yes I record test case in IDE and run it as Junit.

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't know which technologies you're using. How does the code you're running look like? Is it Java (is there anywhere either `Selenium` or `WebDriver` interface being used?), or is it pure Selenese (as seen in IDE)?

Comment: I was using Selenium RC and today migrated to Web driver as it is easier to test such cases.

Comment: So I take it your question is solved? It is quite easy to answer it in both RC and WebDriver